# MYSQL - how to set multiple values in same column and row mysql

Tags: mysql

I am trying to insert several values to a row in same column.
for instance: where ID = 5 to set in column1 values: 4,7,9 but not as a string.

Comment: Storing comma delimited values in a single column is almost always a really bad idea if you intend to treat them as individual values later on; in a database thats what Tables are for. (I.e. create a table with 2 columns & 3 rows of 5,4|5,7|5,9 etc)

Comment: Pls explain what u r trying to do. Why on earth store 4,7,9?

Answer (score 1):

you calso store it in a SET

**Table**

```
CREATE TABLE `jj` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `s` set('1','2','3') DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

and insert like this :

```
INSERT INTO `jj` (`id`, `s`)
VALUES
    (3, '2'),
    (4, '2,3');
```

**sample**

```
MariaDB [l]> SELECT * FROM jj;
+----+------+
| id | s    |
+----+------+
|  1 | 2    |
|  2 | 2    |
|  3 | 2    |
|  4 | 2,3  |
+----+------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [l]> INSERT INTO `jj` (`id`, `s`)
    -> VALUES
    ->     (5, '1,3'),
    ->     (6, '1,2');
Query OK, 2 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Records: 2  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

MariaDB [l]> SELECT * FROM jj;
+----+------+
| id | s    |
+----+------+
|  1 | 2    |
|  2 | 2    |
|  3 | 2    |
|  4 | 2,3  |
|  5 | 1,3  |
|  6 | 1,2  |
+----+------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [l]>
```

Comment: Its almost always a really bad idea storing comma delimited strings like this

Comment: @RiggsFolly - it cant be a bad idea to store things in core datatypes of a DB. SET is designed to do that. this is the definition of SET from MAriaDB: **A set. A string object that can have zero or more values, each of which must be chosen from the list of values 'value1', 'value2', ... A SET column can have a maximum of 64 members. SET values are represented internally as integers.**

Comment: @RiggsFolly - so you do not store a string in a set, you store a bitmask. Mysql only converts the string to the bitfields. It the same when you store a string "2017-01-01 12:00:00" in a timestamp.

Comment: Except you dont know thats what OP is trying to do! And just for reference OP is trying to store `4,7,9`

Comment: He is most likely trying to store `id` numbers from another table. Thats usually what this type of question is about. And really should be answered with the comment ___Bad database design___

Comment: @RiggsFolly - to do this your answer is 100% correct

Comment: I am not saying your answer is bad, just that it might have missed the point. Alternatively you might well have struck lucky

Comment: how can I create SET values that contain all IDs from another table?

Answer (score -1):

Change the design of you table to:

```
ID |  Column1
---+----------
5  |    4
5  |    7
5  |    9
```

Then you can select with:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE ID = 5
```

to get all your values.